# Not reading input from client in socket programming (C)

Tags: c, sockets, server

Below is a admin login handler that takes admin password from client and compares it with ADMIN_PASSWORD .
But when the client is entering the password nothing is happening , not even returning false.
I suppose that the input from client is not being passed correctly to server.

server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<strings.h>


#include "./constants/constants.h"
#include "./handler/admin.h"
#include "./handler/customer.h"

//handler decleration

void connection_handler(int connectionFD);

int main()
{
    int socketFD , bindStatus ,listenStatus,connectionFD;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress , clientAddress;
    int client_size;


    //creating socket for server
    
    socketFD = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(socketFD<0){
        perror("Error while creating server socket");
        _exit(0);
    }
    printf("Server socket created successfully!!\n");

    
    //bind the socket to all avaliable  interface i.e. any IPv4 address can connect to server.
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(8800);
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; //  IPv4

    bindStatus = bind(socketFD , (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress));

    if(bindStatus<0){
        perror("Error while binding socket ");
        close(socketFD);
        _exit(0);
    }

    printf("Server socket binded successfully!!\n");
    
    listenStatus = listen(socketFD, 4);//server can listen to 4 client

    if(listenStatus<0){
        perror("Error while listening for clients");
        close(socketFD);
        _exit(0);
    }

    printf("Listening for clients!!\n");


    while(1)
    {
        client_size = (int)sizeof(clientAddress);
        connectionFD = accept(socketFD , (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress , &client_size);
        if(connectionFD<0){
            perror("Error while connecting to client!");
            close(socketFD);
            _exit(0);
        }
        else{
            if(fork()==0){
                printf("Client Successfully connected to server!!\n");
                connection_handler(connectionFD);
                close(connectionFD);
            }
        }
    }
    close(socketFD);
    return 0 ;
}

//defining the connection handler

void connection_handler(int connectionFD){
    printf("In the server handler\n");
    
    char readBuffer[500] , writeBuffer[500];
    int readBytes , writeBytes;
    int choice;

    writeBytes = write(connectionFD,INITIAL_DAILOGUE,sizeof(INITIAL_DAILOGUE));
    if(writeBytes<0){
        perror("Error while sending the first screen");
    }
    else{
        //zeroing a byte string 
        bzero(readBuffer , sizeof(readBuffer));
        readBytes = read(connectionFD,readBuffer , sizeof(readBuffer));
        if(readBytes<0){
            perror("Error while reading choice of client ");
        }
        else{
            choice = atoi(readBuffer);//convert character string to interger
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    //admin
                    admin_handler(connectionFD);    
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //customer
                    customer_handler(connectionFD);
                    break;
                default:
                    //wrong option 
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

client.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<strings.h>

void connection_handler(int connectionFD);

int main()
{
    int socketFD , bindStatus ,connectionStatus;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;

    socketFD = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(socketFD<0){
        perror("Error while creating server socket!");
        _exit(0);
    }

    printf("Socket Created Successfully!!\n");

    serverAddress.sin_family =AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port=htons(8800);

    connectionStatus = connect(socketFD , (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress));
    if(connectionStatus<0){
        perror("Error while connecting to server!");
        close(socketFD);
        _exit(0);
    }

    connection_handler(socketFD);
    close(socketFD);
    return 0;

}

void connection_handler(int socketFD){
    printf("In the client handler\n");

    int readBytes , writeBytes;
    char readBuffer[1000] , writeBuffer[1000];

    bzero(readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer));
    bzero(writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer));

    readBytes = read(socketFD,readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer));
    if(readBytes<0){
        perror("Error while reading from the server");
        return ;
    }
    printf("%s\n",readBuffer);

    while(readBytes>0){

        bzero(readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer));
        bzero(writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer));

        scanf("%c",writeBuffer);
        writeBytes = write(socketFD,writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer));
        if(writeBytes <0){
            perror("Error while sending client input to server!");
            return;
        }

        readBytes = read(socketFD,readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer));
        if(readBytes<0){
            perror("Error while reading from the server");
            return ;
        }

        printf("%s\n",readBuffer);
    
    }


}
```

```
bool admin_login_handler(int connectionFD){
    int readBytes , writeBytes;
    char readBuffer[500] , writeBuffer[500];

    int admin_id ;
    bzero(writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
    strcpy(writeBuffer,ADMIN_LOGIN_WELCOME);
    strcat(writeBuffer,ADMIN_PASSWORD_PROMPT);

    writeBytes = write(connectionFD, writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer));
    if(writeBytes<0){
        perror("Error while displaying Admin Welcome Prompt!");
        return false;
    }
    bzero(readBuffer , sizeof(readBuffer));
    readBytes = read(connectionFD,readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer));
    if(readBytes<0){
        perror("Error while reading Admin password!");
        return false;
    }
    char password[500];
    bzero(password,sizeof(password));
    strcpy(password , readBuffer);

    if(!strcmp(password, ADMIN_PASSWORD)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


void admin_handler(int connectionFD){
    int readBytes , writeBytes;
    char readBuffer[500], writeBuffer[500];

    if(admin_login_handler(connectionFD)){
        bzero(readBuffer ,sizeof(readBuffer));
        bzero(writeBuffer , sizeof(writeBuffer));

        strcpy(writeBuffer ,ADMIN_LOGIN_SUCCESS);
       //using while loop 
        strcpy(writeBuffer, ADMIN_MENU);
        writeBytes = write(connectionFD,writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer));
        if(writeBytes<0){
            perror("Error while displaying admin menu!");
        }
        readBytes = read(connectionFD , readBuffer ,sizeof(readBuffer));
        if(readBytes<0){
            perror("Error while reading admin choice!");
        }
        
        int admin_choice = atoi(readBuffer);

        switch(admin_choice){
            case 1:
                //add_customer();
                break;
            case 2:
                //modify_customer_details();
                break;
            case 3:
                //delete_customer();
                break;
            case 4:
                //check_customer_details();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        }


    {
       bzero(writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer));
       strcpy(writeBuffer,ADMIN_LOGIN_FAILED);

       writeBytes = write(connectionFD,writeBuffer , sizeof(writeBuffer));
       if(writeBytes<0){
        perror("Error while diplaying admin login failed prompt");
       }
    }
}
```

**Edited**

Added the client and server files. The server calls the admin_handler.
Looking for the password entered by the client to terminate  after pressing enter (\n) but that is not happening in the above case?

Comment: It is not productive to debug incomplete code snippets. Please provide a [mre]. For example, we don't have the client code so how do we know it isn't that part that is wrong? We also don't have any of the socket setup code so don't know if that may be wrong either. Finally, we also need the MRE to be able to reproduce for ourselves.

Comment: `Does it has something to do with newline character received from previous input of client ?` Why are you asking us? We cannot check that. You can.

Comment: I think `sizeof(writeBuffer)` is wrong in `write` function. Probability it should be `strlen(writeBuffer)`

Comment: *"nothing is happening , not even returning false"* - this means that the function is hanging in `read(connectionFD, ...)`, waiting for input on the socket. This is a blocking operation (unless the file descriptor was set to non-blocking) which means that it will wait until at least one byte was delivered from the peer. Why no data are delivered cannot be said based on what you provide as information, i.e. context where the function is called is missing and also the client side - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich updated the client side .

Comment: @kakarot-757: this is just a code dump without any documentation what it should do and how it should be used. I don't see any code in the client to read a password - there is only a single sscanf with %c, which reads only a single character. Also the writes are obviously wrong since they send the whole buffer instead of only the relevant part - see earlier comments here about this. I recommend that you a) strip down your code to the essential part (that's the "Minimal" required), document how to use it, what you expect it to at the various stages of the program and what happens instead.